# How to refernce a property of self when declaring types?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a type

```
type O = {
    x: number;
    y: string;
    z: null;
};
```

Now, I can create a type that gives me the possible value of this type's keys like

```
type K = keyof O;
```

What I want to do now is something like

```
type Derived = {
    k: K;
    v: O[this.k]; // something that can access actual value of k
};

const derived = {
    k: 'x', // IntelliSense comes 'x', 'y', 'z'
    v: 'something',
}
```

What I want to do is tie the `v` property to the value of `k` so that if `k` is `'x'`, ts forces me to write a number and throws an error when it is anything other than a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the keys of `O` and map those to a new type like so:

```
type Derived = {
    [k in keyof O]: { k: k; v: O[k] };
}[keyof O];
```

Comment: Not what I asked for but it works and kinda does what I want to. Thank you.